# Proxy objects in iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, ppl

I have a big vector of items that belong to a certain class.

```
struct item {
    int class_id;
    //some other data...
};
```

The same `class_id` can appear multiple times in the vector, and the vector is constructed once and then sorted by `class_id`. So all elements of the same class are next to each other in the vector.

I later have to process the items per class, ie. I update all items of the same class but I do not modify any item of a different class. Since I have to do this for all items and the code is trivially parallelizable I wanted to use Microsoft PPL with `Concurrency::parallel_for_each()`. Therefore I needed an iterator and came up with a forward iterator that returns the range of all items with a certain `class_id` as proxy object. The proxy is simply a `std::pair` and the proxy is the iterator's value type.

```
using item_iterator = std::vector<item>::iterator;
using class_range = std::pair<item_iterator, item_iterator>;

//iterator definition
class per_class_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, class_range> { /* ... */ };
```

By now I was able to loop over all my classes and update the items like this.

```
std::vector<item> items;
//per_class_* returns a per_class_iterator
std::for_each(items.per_class_begin(), items.per_class_end(),
[](class_range r) 
{ 
    //do something for all items in r 
    std::for_each(r.first, r.second, /* some work */);
});
```

When replacing `std::for_each` with `Concurrency::parallel_for_each` the code crashed. After debugging I found the problem to be the following code in `_Parallel_for_each_helper` in ppl.h at line 2772 ff.

```
// Add a batch of work items to this functor's array
for (unsigned int _Index=0; (_Index < _Size) && (_First != _Last); _Index++)
{
    _M_element[_M_len++] = &(*_First++);
}
```

It uses postincrement (so a temporary iterator is returned), dereferences that temporary iterator and takes the address of the dereferenced item. This only works if the item returned by dereferencing a temporary object survives, ie. basically if it points directly into the container. So fixing this is easy, albeit the per class `std::for_each` work loop has to be replaced with a for-loop.

```
//it := iterator somewhere into the vector of items (item_iterator)
for(const auto cur_class = it->class_id; cur_class == it->class_id; ++it)
{
    /* some work */
}
```

My question is if returning proxy objects the way I did is violating the standard or if the assumption that every iterator dereferences into permanent data has been made by Microsoft for their library, but is not documented. At least I could not find any documentation on the iterator requirements for `parallel_for_each()` except that either a random access or a forward iterator are expected. I have seen [the question about forward iterators and vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560912/how-to-declare-the-value-of-an-iterator-through-decltype) but since my iterator's reference type is `const value_type&` I still think my iterator is ok by the standard. So is a forward iterator returning a proxy object still a valid forward iterator? Or put another way, is it ok for an iterator to have a value type different from a type that is actually stored somewhere in a container?

### Compilable example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <ppl.h>


using identifier = int;
struct item
{
    identifier class_id;
    // other data members
    // ...

    bool operator<(const item &rhs) const
    {
        return class_id < rhs.class_id;
    }

    bool operator==(const item &rhs) const
    {
        return class_id == rhs.class_id;
    }

    //inverse operators omitted
};
using container = std::vector<item>;
using item_iterator = typename container::iterator;
using class_range = std::pair<item_iterator, item_iterator>;

class per_class_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, class_range>
{
public:
    per_class_iterator() = default;
    per_class_iterator(const per_class_iterator&) = default;
    per_class_iterator& operator=(const per_class_iterator&) = default;

    explicit per_class_iterator(container &data) :
        data_(std::addressof(data)),
        class_(equal_range(data_->front())), //this would crash for an empty container. assume it's not.
        next_(class_.second)
    {
        assert(!data_->empty()); //a little late here
        assert(std::is_sorted(std::cbegin(*data_), std::cend(*data_)));
    }

    reference operator*()
    {
        //if data_ is unset the iterator is an end iterator. dereferencing end iterators is bad.
        assert(data_ != nullptr);
        return class_;
    }

    per_class_iterator& operator++()
    {
        assert(data_ != nullptr);

        //if we are at the end of our data
        if(next_ == data_->end())
        {
            //reset the data pointer, ie. make iterator an end iterator
            data_ = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            //set to the class of the next element
            class_ = equal_range(*next_);
            //and update the next_ iterator
            next_ = class_.second;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    per_class_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        per_class_iterator tmp{*this};
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator!=(const per_class_iterator &rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return (data_ != rhs.data_) ||
            (data_ != nullptr && rhs.data_ != nullptr && next_ != rhs.next_);
    }

    bool operator==(const per_class_iterator &rhs) const noexcept
    {
        return !(*this != rhs);
    }

private:
    class_range equal_range(const item &i) const
    {
        return std::equal_range(data_->begin(), data_->end(), i);
    }

    container* data_ = nullptr;
    class_range class_;
    item_iterator next_;
};

per_class_iterator per_class_begin(container &c)
{
    return per_class_iterator{c};
}

per_class_iterator per_class_end()
{
    return per_class_iterator{};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<item> items;
    items.push_back({1});
    items.push_back({1});
    items.push_back({3});
    items.push_back({3});
    items.push_back({3});
    items.push_back({5});
    //items are already sorted

//#define USE_PPL
#ifdef USE_PPL
    Concurrency::parallel_for_each(per_class_begin(items), per_class_end(),
#else
    std::for_each(per_class_begin(items), per_class_end(),
#endif
        [](class_range r)
        {
            //this loop *cannot* be parallelized trivially
            std::for_each(r.first, r.second,
                [](item &i)
                {
                    //update item (by evaluating all other items of the same class) ...
                    //building big temporary data structure for all items of same class ...
                    //i.processed = true;
                    std::cout << "item: " << i.class_id << '\n';
                });
        });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `items`? Is it a `std::vector<class_range>`?

Comment: First look I'd think that an iterator returning a proxy would be ok and was mildly upset that `parallel_for_each` would use direct pointers. But cppreference.com lists this as a condition for forward iterator "If a and b compare equal (a == b is contextually convertible to true) then either they are both non-dereferenceable or *a and *b are references bound to the same object" which would be a problem because the two proxies (even if they look and act the same) would not be the same object. Though I don't know how strictly this is held up by the standard's wording (haven't looked).

Comment: Why not `using per_class_iterator = std::vector<class_range>::iterator` instead of `class per_class_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, class_range> { /* ... */ };`?

Comment: Or how about a `std::multimap` with class_id as the key?

Comment: @flatmouse: Sorry, items is std::vector<item>. I've edited my post. (That also explains your second question, why per_class_iterator is not a typedef to a std::vector<class_range>::iterator, because that vector does not exist.)
And multimap is not used because I know I want a std::vector, since I can preallocate the exact number of elements and do not need any tree structures. I've profiled the code and a sorted std::vector is the fastest and most space efficient version I tested. Even an unordered_multimap allocates unused buckets which is not acceptable in my case.

Comment: If `items` contains `item` elements, then how can the lambda `[](class_range r)` accept `class_range` items?

Comment: @flatmouse: You are absolutely right. I fixed my code again. I guess my brain compiler is not working, so I should have tested my example code in a real compiler. Sorry.

Comment: Would it help to do a loop of `std::equal_range` calls and use those iterators for your parallel call?

Comment: From what is posted this should work, but if it is not working then there must be something else. We don't know what is happening in ` { /* ... */ }` for the class iterator and it might help to see what is done in `per_class_*`. I'm still curious to know why `per_class_iterator` is declared the way it is. Please post an [mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: I think you are right. Especially the third point (about incrementing `It`) of the [Multipass guarantee](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (where your quote is taken from) says "either `It` is a raw pointer type or [...]" which a proxy is clearly not. I have to check if a proxy iterator can fulfill the other condition where `(void)++It(a), *a` should be equivalent to `*a`.

Comment: @Galik That's basically what the iterator does. It calls `std::equal_range` and stores the returned result. Incrementing calls `equal_range` for the next `class_id` (read from the end iterator of the previous call to equal_range). I will provide an actually compilable example as flatmouse suggested tomorrow, since I do not have access to MSVC now.

Comment: @user2460318 But your iterator is using a proxy. I thought  making an equal_range loop directly would give you direct iterators and shouldn't really be much more cumbersome that the loop you have.

Comment: There have always been problems with proxy iterators - perhaps the newer +14 or +17 versions of the language enable them with no (or fewer) problems.  But, for example, see this article: [To Be or Not to Be (an Iterator), by Eric Niebler](http://ericniebler.com/2015/01/28/to-be-or-not-to-be-an-iterator/) for an explanation of the issues - which includes a discussion of why the "requirements for an iterator" are not exactly what you think they are (for forward, random, etc.).

Comment: @flatmouse "Minimal" example added. It's still just below 150 lines.

Comment: @Galik I had loops using equal_range directly, but they cannot be parallelized using PPL. `parallel_for_each` requires iterators and `parallel_for` requires a fixed increment. That's why I tried hiding the equal_range call behind an iterator in the first place.

Comment: @user2460318 But `std::equal_range` returns 2 iterators. Isn't that what you need for `parallel_for_each`?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I think I have tested all requirements of the multipass guarantee given at cppreference and I think my iterator should be a valid forward iterator as long as "same object" means equality comparable. But I have to assume equality comparable is not enough to be the same object.

Comment: @Galik `std::equal_range` returns two iterators describing the range of same class items. I cannot run in parallel over items of the same class. I can only process different classes in parallel. (See my compilable example or my comment to DarkWanderers answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're writing a proxy iterator, the `reference` type should be a class type, precisely because it can outlive the iterator it is derived from. So, for a proxy iterator, when instantiating the `std::iterator` base should specify the `Reference` template parameter as a class type, typically the same as the value type:

```
class per_class_iterator : public std::iterator<
    std::forward_iterator_tag, class_range, std::ptrdiff_t, class_range*, class_range>
                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Unfortunately, PPL is not keen on proxy iterators and will break compilation:

```
ppl.h(2775): error C2338: lvalue required for forward iterator operator *
ppl.h(2772): note: while compiling class template member function 'Concurrency::_Parallel_for_each_helper<_Forward_iterator,_Function,1024>::_Parallel_for_each_helper(_Forward_iterator &,const _Forward_iterator &,const _Function &)'
        with
        [
            _Forward_iterator=per_class_iterator,
            _Function=main::<lambda_051d98a8248e9970abb917607d5bafc6>
        ]
```

This is actually a `static_assert`:

```
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(*_First)>::value, "lvalue required for forward iterator operator *");
```

This is because the enclosing `class _Parallel_for_each_helper` stores an array of `pointer`s and expects to be able to indirect them later:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<_Forward_iterator>::pointer    _M_element[_Size];
```

Since PPL doesn't check that `pointer` is actually a pointer, we can exploit this by supplying a proxy pointer with an `operator*` and overloading `class_range::operator&`:

```
struct class_range_ptr;
struct class_range : std::pair<item_iterator, item_iterator> {
    using std::pair<item_iterator, item_iterator>::pair;
    class_range_ptr operator&();
};
struct class_range_ptr {
    class_range range;
    class_range& operator*() { return range; }
    class_range const& operator*() const { return range; }
};
inline class_range_ptr class_range::operator&() { return{*this}; }

class per_class_iterator : public std::iterator<
    std::forward_iterator_tag, class_range, std::ptrdiff_t, class_range_ptr, class_range&>
{
    // ...
```

This works great:

```
item: item: 5
1
item: 3item: 1

item: 3
item: 3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay when replying. I had a long weekend. Though your solution clearly violates the forward iterator requirement (`iterator::reference != T&`) it is a perfectly working solution that allows to fool PPL and accept the iterator. Thanks for this suggestion, I really did not think about overloading `operator&()`.

Comment: @ecatmur: Thank you very much for this answer. After reading it everything clicked for my problem. It works perfectly. I still think ppl is doing "the wrong thing" though by assuming that iterator values must must point to somehow externally allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

For your direct question, no, iterator does not have to be something which is related to any kind of container. [About only requirements for an iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) are for it to be:

- be copy-constructible, copy-assignable and destructible
- support equality/inequality
- be dereferencable

Iterator does not necessarily has to be tied to a particular container (see [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Generators)), and so it cannot be said that "it has to has same type as container" - because there is no container in generic case.

It seems, hovever, having a custom iterator class may be actually an overkill in your case. Here's why:

In C++, array/vector end iterator is and iterator pointing just behind the end of the last item.

Given a vector of objects of "classes" (in your definition) A,B,C, etc., filled like following:

```
AAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCD.......
```

You can just take regular vector iterators that will act as your range starts and ends:

```
AAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCD......Z
^      ^           ^      ^       ^
i1     i2          i3     i4      iN
```

For the 4 iterators you see here, following is true:

1. i1 is `begin` iterator for class A
2. i2 is `end` iterator for class A and `begin` iterator for class B
3. i3 is `end` iterator for class B and `begin` iterator for class C etc.

Hence, for each class you can have a pair of iterators which are start and end of the respective class range.

Hence, your processing is as trivial as:

```
for(auto it = i1; i!= i2; i++) processA(*it);
for(auto it = i2; i!= i3; i++) processB(*it);
for(auto it = i3; i!= i4; i++) processC(*it);
```

Each loop being trivially parallelizable.

```
parallel_for_each (i1; i2; processA);
parallel_for_each (i2; i3; processB);
parallel_for_each (i3; i4; processC);
```

To use a range-based `for`, you can introduce a substitute range class:

```
class vector_range<T> {
    public:
        vector<T>::const_iterator begin() {return _begin;};
        vector<T>::const_iterator end() {return _end;};
    // Trivial constructor filling _begin and _end fields
}
```

That is to say, you don't really need a proxy iterators to parallelize loops - the way C++ iterators are done is already ideally covers your case.

Comment: This is true, but the opposite of what I actually want. I want to process items of _different classes in parallel_, whereas items of the _same class_ have to be _processed in one thread_. I have added a compilable example that shows what I try to achieve.
By reading the comments and links provided in these comments I get the impression that a forward iterator currently has to return a real reference. So it might be that my iterator is violating the ForwardIterator contract.